# Proof of inner product trace matrices on complexe plan

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, trace

How do you prove that tr(B*A) is indeed a inner product? (A and B are matrices on C)
[image]

Comment: this is a proof for R not for C ...

Comment: Like B* is the transpose and conjugate of B

Comment: It is the same inner product as on $\mathbb C^{mn}$...

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Which property of an inner product are you having trouble with?

Comment: no'its not the same on Cmn because  B* its the conjugate transpose of B.

Comment: @RoxaneCohenDawdi it is. Probably you have the wrong idea of the inner product of $\mathbb C^{mn}$.

Comment: @user251257 ah ok, i think that inner product on C satisfied three axioms : positive definiteness, conjugate symmetry, linearity in the first argument, but on R we don't have to prove conjugate symmetry but just symmetry

Comment: @RoxaneCohenDawdi where have I mentioned the reals?

Comment: @user251257 on the link that you put 2 days ago, but its okay i found a solution, thks for all :)

Answer (score 0):

i think i found the solution'but can you say me if it's ok ? [image]

[image]